# read the last modified file in perl

Tags: perl, file, directory, last-modified

How can I read the content of the last modified file in a directory in perl

I have a tool for received sms and I want to give out the content of the last modified file , which is stored in gammu/inbox directory , with a perl script

for example: the script checked if a new sms in folder(gammu/inbox), are they, then give out the content from the last sms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sort the directory according to the age of each file, using the `-M` file test operator. The most recently modified file will then be the first in the list

This program shows the principle. It finds the latest file in the current working directory, prints its name and opens it for input

If you want to do this for a directory other that the cwd then it is probably easiest just to `chdir` to it and use this code than to try to `opendir` a specific directory, as then you will have to build the full path to each file before you can use `-M`

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use feature 'say';

my $newest_file = do {
    opendir my $dh, '.' or die $!;
    my @by_age  = sort { -M $a <=> -M $b } grep -f, readdir $dh;
    $by_age[0];
};

say $newest_file;

open my $fh, '<', $newest_file or die qq{Unable to open "$newest_file" for input: $!};
```

If you are working with a sizeable directory then this may take some time as a `stat` operation is quite slow. You can improve this a lot by using a *Schwartzian Transform* so that `stat` is called only once for each file

```
my $newest_file = do {

    opendir my $dh, '.' or die $!;

    my @by_age  = map $_->[0],
    sort { $a->[1] <=> $b->[1] }
    map [ $_, -M ], readdir $dh;

    $by_age[0];
};
```

If you want something *really* fast, then just do a single pass of the files, keeping track of the newest found so far. Like this

```
my $newest_file = do {

    opendir my $dh, '.' or die $!;

    my ($best_file, $best_age);

    while ( readdir $dh ) {

        next unless -f;
        my $age = -M _;

        unless ( defined $best_age and $best_age < $age ) {
            $best_age = $age;
            $best_file = $_;
        }
    }

    $best_file;
};
```

Comment: with this script i see the last sms, then i received but not the content of this sms. Thanks

Comment: @perlfg: Do you need to be told how to open a file and print it?

Comment: no :) I receive constantly sms and would echo the content of the last sms with perl

Answer (score 0):

You need to get an ordered list of file with

```
use File::DirList;
my @list = File::DirList::list('your_directory', 'M');
```

Than the first element of list is what you are looking for.

You can read more about the library here [File::DirList](http://search.cpan.org/~tpaba/File-DirList-0.04/lib/File/DirList.pm)

Comment: This won't work for many reasons. You clearly haven't tested it.