# check last modified file in directory

Tags: perl, file, directory, dirname

My script to check the last modified file in this directory /var/spool/gammu/inbox/

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use warnings;
chomp (my $dirname ='/var/spool/gammu/inbox/');
my $newest_file = do {
opendir my $dh, $dirname or die "Could not open '$dirname' for reading: $!\n";
my @by_age  = sort { -M $a <=> -M $b } grep -f, readdir ($dh);
$by_age[0];
};

open my $file, '<', $newest_file or die qq{Unable to open "$newest_file" for input: $!};
my @rows = <$file>;
close ($file);
print "@rows\n";
```

I'm getting:

Use of uninitialized value $newest_file in open at ./checken.pl line 16.

Use of uninitialized value $newest_file in concatenation (.) or string at ./checken.pl line 16.

Unable to open "" for input: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden at ./checken.pl line 16.

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest you to prep-end the directory name before file(to give absolute path) using `map` and then feed it to `grep`.

It should look like below:

```
my @by_age  = sort {-M $a <=> -M $b} grep {-f $_} map {"$dirname/$_"} readdir ($dh);
```

Comment: How can i make this script running with while or for. everytime script check if i have a new file.

Comment: wrap it under `while(1) { sleep(your seconds)}`.

Comment: script checkt everytime the directory and should only provide an answer me when a new file is created.

Comment: Then, probably you should look at [`File::Modified`](http://search.cpan.org/~neilb/File-Modified-0.10/lib/File/Modified.pm) and [`File::Monitor`](http://search.cpan.org/~andya/File-Monitor-1.00/lib/File/Monitor.pm)

Comment: @perlfg: You have not yet accepted any answer for any of your questions. Kindly check this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I didn't emphasize this enough in [my solution to your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36520011/622310). I wrote

> If you want to do this for a directory other that the cwd then it is probably easiest just to `chdir` to it and use this code than to try to `opendir` a specific directory, as then you will have to build the full path to each file before you can use `-M`

The problem is that the data returned by `readdir` is just a bare file name without any path information, and if the file is in a directory other than the current working directory then it won't be found without adding path information

If you just `chdir` to the directory first then everything will work fine. Here's a tidied version of your code

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

chomp(my $dirname = "/var/spool/gammu/inbox/");
chdir $dirname or die qq{Unable to chdir to "$dirname": $!};

my $newest_file = do {
    opendir my $dh, '.' or die "Could not open '$dirname' for reading: $!\n";
    my @by_age  = sort { -M $a <=> -M $b } grep -f, readdir ($dh);
    $by_age[0];
};

open my $file, '<', $newest_file or die qq{Unable to open "$newest_file" for input: $!};
print while <$file>;
```

Or, if you have a reason to avoid changing the directory in your program (the change won't be reflected in your shell once the program exits), then you should use `rel2abs` from `File::Spec::Functions` to construct the full file path before working with it

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Spec::Functions 'rel2abs';

chomp(my $dirname = "/var/spool/gammu/inbox/");

my $newest_file = do {
    opendir my $dh, '.' or die "Could not open '$dirname' for reading: $!\n";
    my @files = map { rel2abs($_, $dirname) } grep -f, readdir ($dh);
    my @by_age  = sort { -M $a <=> -M $b } @files;
    $by_age[0];
};

open my $file, '<', $newest_file or die qq{Unable to open "$newest_file" for input: $!};
print while <$file>;
```

Some other points

- `use warnings` is superior to `-w` on the command line. You shouldn't use both
- It's best to avoid reading a whole file into memory unless you need to. A file can be read and printed one line at a time

Comment: Thanks :))))))))))))